# Evaluate inline r code in rmarkdown figure caption

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using RStudio and knitr to knit .Rmd to .docx

I would like to include inline code in figure captions e.g. something like the following in the chunk options:

fig.cap = "Graph of `nrow(data)` data points"

However, knitr does not evaluate this code, instead just printing the unevaluated command.

Is there a way to get knitr to evaluate r code in figure/table captions?

Comment: Please try `paste("Graph of", nrow(data), "data points")`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`knitr` evaluates chunk options as R code. Therefore, to include a variable value in a figure caption, just compose the required string using `paste` or `sprintf`:

```
fig.cap = paste("Graph of", nrow(data), "data points")
```

---

Note that this might be problematic if `data` is created *inside this* chunk (and not in a previous chunk) because by default chunk options are evaluated *before* the chunk itself is evaluated.

To solve this issue, use the package option [`eval.after`](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#package_options) to have the option `fig.cap` be evaluated after the chunk itself has been evaluated:

```
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(eval.after = "fig.cap")
```

Here a complete example:

````
---
title: "SO"
output: 
  word_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
---


```{r fig.cap = paste("Graph of", nrow(iris), "data points.")}
plot(iris)
```


```{r setup}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(eval.after = "fig.cap")
```

```{r fig.cap = paste("Graph of", nrow(data2), "data points.")}
data2 <- data.frame(1:10)
plot(data2)
```
````

The first figure caption works even without `eval.after` because the `iris` dataset is always available (as long as `datasets` has been attached). Generating the second figure caption would fail without `eval.after` because `data2` does not exist before the last chunk has been evaluated.

Comment: I want to use colnames() instead, but in my case it would be part of a fig.cap in a chunk with a for loop that outputs a different graph in each iteration. Each graph is representing the first column vs a different column of the same dataframe, being the respective names of the different columns what i want to be shown in the caption of each graph. Is it possible to do this? i tried paste0("graph for",colnames(dataframe)[i]), but the same colname shows in all instances.

Comment: @ForEverNewbie If I understand your problem correctly, you need to skip the `[i]`: try `paste("graph for", colnames(dataframe))`.

Comment: that works if the graphs are in the same chunk but  executed independently with plot(), but if they are part of a `for` loop, then there is no caption for any of the graphs. A simple exaple of what i mean would be: ```{r chunkname,fig.cap=colnames(mtcars)[1:2]}
for(i in 2:3){
plot(mtcars$wt,mtcars[,i])
}
```